# Jetpack Compose - flagNoPersonalizedLearning

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

On `EditView`, one could add an `imeOption` for `flagNoPersonalizedLearning`. This is particularly useful for password and other fields, to inform the input system to NOT learn from the input on that field. I can find `imeOptions` on trough `KeyboardOptions` on `TextField`, but no option seem to resemble the flag described above. Is this something that is currently missing from Compose input fields, or did I miss something ?